# fontsize package changes indent of first line in paragraphs?

Tags: indentation, fontsize, paragraphs

Take the LaTeX source below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontsize}
%\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

First paragraph.

Second paragraph.

\end{document}
```

The result is that the indent of "Second paragraph." is smaller than if you do not use the fontsize package. Alternatively, you can uncomment the line `\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}` and also restore the usual indent.

Is that maybe a bug? Or am I maybe not using the package correctly?

(Explicitly setting `\usepackage[fontsize=10pt]{fontsize}` makes no difference.)

TeXLive 2021 on Mac:

- LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
  L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
- Mac OS Catalina: 10.15.7 (19H524)

Comment: It seems a precise choice by the package author. In my opinion there should be an option to decide the length of `\parindent` independent of what font size is chosen.

Comment: I may have found out why this in done:

From the "Unofficial LaTeX2e reference manual" in section "15.3 \parindent & \parskip":

https://latexref.xyz/_005cparindent-_0026-_005cparskip.html

"In standard LaTeX documents, the default value for \parindent in one-column documents is 15pt when the default text size is 10pt, 17pt for 11pt, and 1.5em for 12pt. In two-column documents it is 1em."

So rules for "traditional" sizes would be too arbitrary to adapt automatically to intermediate font sizes in a natural way.

Comment: I contacted the maintainer: An option to set `\parindent` is already implemented and will be released soon. (Ephemeral detail: He told me to "please ignore the version 0.8.2 which should come out [today] or Monday" since the implementation there turned out to be slightly buggy; a new version with a fix for that is in the making and would normally come out just a few days later.)

Answer (score 2):

Since version 0.8.3 the `fontsize` package provides the `parindent` option:

```
\usepackage[fontsize=11.7pt,parindent=35pt]{fontsize}
```

The issue is not definitely closed because there are some problems in defining `\parindent` through the package. For example if you set `parindent=1em`, i.e. using a font-dependent unit, you will get different values depending on both the font used and on how it is loaded.

The `cochineal` package, for example, calls `\normalfont` inside the `\AtEndPreamble` hook. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{cochineal}
%\normalfont
\usepackage[fontsize=11.7pt,parindent=1em]{fontsize}

\begin{document}
 
 parindent=\the\parindent
 
\end{document}
```

In this case

```
parindent=11.74713pt
```

But with `\normalfont` after `\usepackage{cochineal}` you will get

```
parindent=11.7pt
```

In fact this is independent of the `fontsize` package. Using

```
\parindent=1em
```

before or after `\begin{document}` gives in any case two different values for the `\parindent`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cochineal}
\parindent=1em

\begin{document}
%\parindent=1em
 
 parindent=\the\parindent
 
\end{document}
```